# Check server for notifications for app and display them if present

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, background, notifications

I am creating an application on Android which has a MySql server. I want a notification if there is any data present in the File (The User has the job to remove it all but after verifying them). So, I need a good background worker which activates after one hour, checks if any data is there, send a notification, close itself and then again activate after one hour. The time **one hour** can be changed. I use a AsyncTask for downloading(Unavoidable). I am good at sending notifications and using AsyncTask.

I am a bit lazy so have not done any experiment before verifying that it will complete my task.

I think it may use the **Service** class. Please provide detailed information. Please give a whole tutorial when telling to use any *Github Library* cause I am new to Github.

Thank You,

Yours Respectfully,

India's youngest android application developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution Myself and so decided to help out any other new Programmer. Here it is-

**AlarmReceiverLifeLog.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiverLifeLog extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "LL24";
    static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.v(TAG, "Alarm for LifeLog...");

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,MyReciever.class);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

**MyReciever.java**

```
public class MyReciever extends Service {

int mStartMode;
IBinder mBinder;
boolean mAllowRebind;

@Override
public void onCreate() {

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //Your Method to get Data from Server
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    return mAllowRebind;
}

@Override
public void onRebind(Intent intent) {

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

}
//method to show notification to be called when you finally decide that you have to notify the user
public void showNotification(String title,String message){
    Log.d("Service","Going to show notification");
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(message);



    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NavigationActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
}
```

Add this in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiverLifeLog" >
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".MyReciever" />
```

Activating the reciever

```
Intent ll24 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverLifeLog.class);
    PendingIntent recurringLl24 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, ll24,     PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_DAY, recurringLl24);//For waking it after each 12hrs.
```